# Check actual file type in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, mime, file-type

I want to prevent people from, say, uploading a movie file or shell script by just adding a `jpg` extension to my avatar upload endpoint. I haven't written the backend to upload script in a long time but I remember PHP being able to tell me the *actual* file type, not just the type based on the file extension. I can also check this purely on the front-end JS. Or in Java there's http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29

The issue is in vanilla Node and using a bunch of mime related modules including `mmmagic` are just returning the mime type based on the file extension. For example, I removed the `gif` extension on a gif file and changed it to `txt` and both Node and `mmmagic` just return `text/plain`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, I was using [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), which is a mime type detector tool. Turns out, there is nodejs bridge for it, [node-tika](https://github.com/mattcg/node-tika).

To use

```
npm install node-tika
```

and

```
var tika = require('tika');

tika.type('test/data/file.pdf', function(err, contentType) {
  console.log(contentType); // Logs 'application/pdf'.
});
```